# react component: how to set a key only attribute from props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building a simple react-native component, which uses itself a component which requires an attribue which is only a key. For example:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LineChart bezier />
    );
  }
}
```

The component my component uses is `LineChart`, which expects an attribute like `bezier`.
I don't know how I could pass this attribute to `LineChart` in a dynamic way, i.e. using a prop... I did try something like:

```
<LineChart this.props.interpolation />
```

But this is not syntactically valid.

Any clue?

Comment: "key only props" are actually booleans. So when you do `<Comp bezier />` you are just saying the same as `<Comp bezier={true} />` in a shorter way. If you want to have it dynamic, you can do something like `<Com bezier={this.props.bezier} interpolation={this.props.interpolation} />` considering that the values inside `props` will be booleans.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I didn't realize it was a shortcut for a boolean... My bad... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"key only props" are actually booleans.

So when you do `<Component bezier />` you are just saying the same as `<Component bezier={true} />` in a shorter way.

If you want to have it dynamic, you can do something like

```
const { bezier, interpolation } = this.props;

return <Component bezier={bezier} interpolation={interpolation} />
```

PS: considering that the values inside props will be booleans.

Answer (score 0):

I have used functional component in which i pass key like that

```
<LineChart bezier={Your_DATA}/>
```